# Error: value of type 'String' has no member 'Generator' in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this piece of code in Swift:

```
var password = "Meet me in St. Louis"
for character in password {
    if character == "e" {
        print("found an e!")
    } else {
    }
}
```

which throws the following error: `value of type 'String' has no member 'Generator' in Swift` in line: `for character in password`

I have tried to find online the possible error, but I can't (plus I am new to Swift and trying to navigate myself through the idiosyncrasies of the language).

Any help would be much appreciated (plus a brief explanation of what I am missing if possible)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order for your code to work you need to do this :

```
var password = "Meet me in St. Louis"
for character in password.characters {
    if character == "e" {
        print("found an e!")
    } else {
    }
}
```

The problem with your code not working was the fact that it was not iterating  over your array looking for a particular Character. Changing it to `password.characters` forces `i` to "search" each Character of the array `password` and voila.This behaviour happens in swift 2.0 because `String` no longer conforms to `SequenceType` protocol while `String.CharacterView` does!